# Maximum Independent Set of a Tree using Greedy Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees, greedy-algorithms, independent-sets

I was attempting to solve "Maximum Independent Set of a Tree" and came up with an algorithm that resembled this one [Why is greedy algorithm not finding maximum independent set of a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921679/why-is-greedy-algorithm-not-finding-maximum-independent-set-of-a-graph/13922055#13922055)

Code extract shown here:

```
Greedy(G):
S = {}
While G is not empty:
    Let v be a node with minimum degree in G
    S = union(S, {v})
    remove v and its neighbors from G
return S
```

Would this algorithm work for trees? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would work for trees (acyclic graphs in general).

You need to prove one thing.  Let $\ell$ be a leaf in a tree.  Then there exists a maximum independent set that contains $\ell$.

The proof sketch is as follows.  Let $S^*$ be a maximum independent set and assume that $\ell \notin S^*$.  Since it is maximum, the unique neighbor $v$ of $\ell$ is in $S^*$.  Since $v$ is $\ell$'s only neighbor, we can create a new independent set $S = S^* \setminus \{v\} \cup \{\ell\}$ with the same size.

This proves that your code is correct.  (Strictly speaking you also have to argue that you can put isolated vertices in $S$, but that's fine.)